# Stuck trying to import LinkedIn URLS from a web page using google sheets IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I scrape the linkedin urls from the web page below using google sheets

https://investors.atlassian.com/corporate-governance/board-of-directors/default.aspx#

I’ve tried using =IMPORTXML on google sheets but it is only scraping the thumbnail and not the URL connected to the thumbnail

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
[image]

My XPATH is:

```
*//div[@class='social-panel']/a[last()]/@href
```